# Remove item from Shopping Items in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

While working on a Codecadamy exercise on React Hooks, I came across a code that I couldn't understand.

Check this in the following code: onClick={() => removeItem(index)}

```js
<ul>{cart.map((item,index) => <li key={index} onClick={() => removeItem(index)} >{item}</li>)}</ul>
```

Why can't we simply write: onClick={removeItem(index)} // When I tried doing it, the code didn't work.

While I have completed the code, I can understand the difference between `onClick={removeItem(index)}` and `onClick={() => removeItem(index)}`.

In the same code, following example worked well (when I tried to add the item in a list.)

```
{produce.map((item) => <button key={item} value={item} onClick={addItem}>{item}</button>)};
```

In the above example, `onClick={addItem}` worked well.

Here is complete code: https://gist.github.com/sixpl/8141196fc688949ccb51b4459e645b34

Thank you for your time.

Comment: On the add method you are adding a new item to the list so you do not really care about the rest of the items in that list. However, when u want to remove an item from the list you need the item and the index of that item in the list so you can remove just that item.

Comment: `() => removeItem(index)` is an (anonymous) **function**, while `removeItem(index)` is a **function call**. The function call gets executed immediately when it renders, which isn't what you want. `onClick` expects a *function*. The reason we use this anonymous function rather than just passing in the function directly, i.e. `onClick={removeItem}` is because we need to pass the `index` argument in.

Comment: `addItem` works because you don't need to pass an argument to it (the `{target}` parameter you see in the `addItem` function definition) is an instrinsic event value that gets passed in by default in Javascript for the `onClick` attribute

Answer (score 1):

While using `{removeItem(argument)}`, you are actually making a function call. The JSX expression (what you have mentioned inside inside `{ }`) will get evaluated and this function will be called. Wrapping it inside a function ensures that the we are indicating what to call on click but not calling it.
Ex: `{()=>{ yourActualFunctionCall(argument) }}`

While using `{addItem}`, you are indicating that the function to be called on click is `addItem`. Notice, there is no `( )` after the function, so the `addItem` will not be called.

Comment: Thank you. The answer was helpful and I got the point.